# Why does a WCF service redirect to a http for favicon?

Tags: c#, wcf, google-chrome, https

We currently have an issue where in chrome, a WCF service comes up as not secure because a redirect to http is happening even though we are accessing it using HTTPS;

[image]
Is there a way to specify a favicon for the service or disable it altogether?

I have tried adding in the web.config

```
configuration/location[path="favicon.ico"]/httprequest[enabled="false"]
```

but that only seems to work with IE.

There reason why this is an issue for us is that our mobile app is accessing the service and is encountering the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

See method 2. It's your browser requesting it.